# How to disable built-in HLSL compiler for Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio, cmake, hlsl, spir-v, dxc

The topic may sound like a duplicate question but the problem in my case is that I don't have any HLSL files included in the project. Thus, I can not manually disable/change the dxc compiler. Though, I have added a pre-build command using CMake to generate SPIR-V from HLSL files. While compiling the project I get the following error:

> dxc failed : SPIR-V CodeGen not available. Please recompile with -DENABLE_SPIRV_CODEGEN=ON.

meaning that Visual Studio uses the built-in dxc which does not have support for SPIR-V CodeGen. How can I explicitly tell which dxc version to use using CMake?

Answer (score 1):

Explicitly specifying the dxc path to use VulkanSDK's version fixed the issue

```
add_custom_command(
    TARGET ${target}
    PRE_BUILD
    COMMAND $ENV{VULKAN_SDK}/bin/dxc.exe -spirv -fvk-invert-y -T vs_6_0 -E ${vertexEntry} ${file} -Fo ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/Assets/${vertexEntry}.spv
    COMMAND $ENV{VULKAN_SDK}/bin/dxc.exe -spirv -T ps_6_0 -E ${fragmentEntry} ${file} -Fo ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/Assets/${fragmentEntry}.spv
)
```

Comment: How exactly did you implement this in visual studio? I've been struggling with the same issue, but idk where to write this command.